# How to map JSON_ARRAYAGG results with mybatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I can't map the results from `JSON_ARRAYAGG function`.

mybatis mapper:

```
<mapper namespace="com.test.mapper.UserEntityMapper">
    <resultMap id="userMap" type="UserVO">
        <id property="id" column="id" />
        <result property="username" column="username"/>
        <collection property="pictures" ofType="PictureVO">
            <id property="id" column="id" />
            <result property="location" column="location" />
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
    <select id="findUserById" parameterType="map" resultMap="userMap">
        SELECT
        users.id,
        users.username,
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                "id",
                pic.id,
                "location",
                pic.location
            ) 
        ) AS pictures
        FROM
            users
            LEFT JOIN pictures pic ON users.id = pic.user_id 
        WHERE
            users.id = 1
    </select>
</mapper>
```

UserVO model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserVO {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private List<PictureVO> pictures;
}
```

PictureVO model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PictureVO {
    private Long id;
    private String location;
}
```

Results from calling the API:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "connor",
    "pictures": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "location": null
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the `pictures` only have a `id` can be map correctly. And there are suppose 2 results in `pictures`, if I execute the sql directly, and here only 1 returned.

Answer (score 0):

you should set your method's ("findUserById") return type List and MyBatis will complete that automatically.
Try to write it in mapper interface:

```
List<UserVo> findUserById();
```

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis returns Java objects not JSON, so it may be your 'API' that converts the Java objects into JSON.
If I am right, you just need to do the normal MyBatis mapping.

Something like this:

```xml
<resultMap id="userMap" type="UserVO">
  <id property="id" column="id" />
  <result property="username" column="username"/>
  <collection property="pictures" ofType="PictureVO">
    <id property="id" column="picture_id" />
    <result property="location" column="location" />
  </collection>
</resultMap>

<select id="findUserById" parameterType="map" resultMap="userMap">
  SELECT
    users.id,
    users.username,
    pic.id picture_id,
    pic.location
  FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN pictures pic ON users.id = pic.user_id
  WHERE
    users.id = 1
</select>
```

Note that `pic.id` needs an alias to distinguish the column from `users.id` in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use typeHandler.
For instance:

```xml
<resultMap id="userMap" type="UserVO">
        <id property="id" column="id" />
        <result property="username" column="username"/>
        <result property="pictures" column="pictures" 
         typeHandler="com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.handlers.JacksonTypeHandler"
        />
    </resultMap>
```